# php not sense to special characters

Tags: php, encoding, special-characters, mbstring

```
<?php
mb_detect_order('UTF-8,eucjp-win,sjis-win');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
echo mb_internal_encoding();
function convert($a) str_replace('â','a',$string);
$e=$_POST['aaa'];

 ?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
</head>
<form method="post" action="#">
<textarea id="aaa" name="bbb" placeholder="send"  ></textarea>
```

**mb_internal_encoding(); output: "UTF-8"

textarea input: "âb" || php-output:âb  script not convert "â"=>"a"

file is without BOM**

**these may be other reasons?? what else can I try?**

Comment: whats your question ?? posting code and error will never get solution, post what your trying to Achieve and what error you get

Comment: script not convert â=>a

Comment: Try `var_dump(bin2hex('â'))` and tell us the result.

Comment: script properly convert on localhost and on other a host  but on my host not convert special characters

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replice('â','a',$string);
```

should be:

```
 str_replace('â','a',$string);
```

Comment: i am sory, I wrote it down wrong, in script it: "str_replace"

Answer (score 0):

some typos there :

```
function convert($a) str_replice('â','a',$string);
```

should be :

```
function convert($a){return str_replace('â','a',$a);}
```

not `replice()`,`$string` should be `$a` , also if you want to see the output from the function you should `return` it.

so when you call:

```
<?php echo convert("â");?>
```

it would output just fine

Comment: i am sory, I wrote it down wrong, in script it: "str_replace"

Comment: @user1419633, if you try to understand my answer, then your problem is solved , this line `function convert($a){return str_replace('â','a',$a);}` tells everything ;)

Comment: dont solved, its not problem of syntax. on some server script is  properly running. true code "str_replace"